# Why my Flutter app does not connect to my local nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I'm learning nodejs and I want to create real time communication between flutter app and nodejs server. Both working on local.

This is my socket.js file. I'm using express and socket io. (Express for later. For Rest)

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Server is running")
})

//Socket Logic
const socketio = require('socket.io')(http)

socketio.on("connection", (userSocket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
    userSocket.on("message", (data) => {
        userSocket.broadcast.emit("receive_message", data)
    })
})

http.listen(3000,(s)=>{
  console.log("server is listening at 3000");
});
```

My Flutter which use socket_io_client package. When I run my app nothing happend and there is no connection between them.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

String uri = 'http://localhost:3000';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String message;
  IO.Socket socket;
  StreamController<String> _socketResponse;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _socketResponse = StreamController();

    socket = IO.io(
        'http://locaost:3000',
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket']) // for Flutter or Dart VM
            .setExtraHeaders({'foo': 'bar'}) // optional
            .build());

    socket.onConnect((data) {
      print('connectend');
      print(data);
      socket.emit('message', 'tester');
    });

    socket.on('event', (data) => _socketResponse.sink.add(data));

    message = 'Hello ';
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _socketResponse.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<String>(
            stream: _socketResponse.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(snapshot.data ?? socket.connected.toString()),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
I upload my server files to Heroku and now it is working. I think there is a problem at network policy.

Comment: Does "local" mean on one computer or just in the same network?

Comment: @MindStudio on computer.

Comment: Instead of localhost try your IP of your computer on which your node.js server is listening. on the local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Socket-io-client is working with version 2 but my server use socketio version 3. I downgrade my version 3 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem earlier and I solved it by using the local IP of the machine on which the node.js server was running instead of localhost. The issue is that if you are running an emulator then it should be getting it's own IP address from your network due to some configuration of your emulator hence then Flutter app and your node.js are not the on `localhost`.

You can find your IP on the network depending upon your operation system. If you ar using Linux or MacOs then the command will be `ifconfig` and if you are on Windows then it should be `ifconfig`. In the output of the command you can find your adapter which will show the local IP of your machine.

One you will find the IP of the node.js server machine you can update it in your Flutter app.

Assuming that my local IP was 192.168.0.22 and the API was running on port 3000 then my network address would be `http://192.168.0.22:3000` and your connection code will look like this.

```
   socket = IO.io(
        'http://192.168.0.22:3000',
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket']) // for Flutter or Dart VM
            .setExtraHeaders({'foo': 'bar'}) // optional
            .build());
```

Also I will suggest you to create the environment file in your flutter app so you can load the addr from the configuration file because in most of the cases the local network IP is not static and you need to change the IP to your current IP if the problem persist.

Comment: When I tried that it gives me an error "Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)
192.168.2.74:3000
^
"

Comment: I just updated the answer. Add `http://` before addr.

Comment: connection. Flutter is  still not connecting server

Comment: when i create html file and try to connect server with javascript, It is working but flutter has problem.

Comment: I tried some other packages but they are also not working.

Comment: Maybe you are putting the correct local IP.

Comment: No, I looked at my ip address from ifconfig and system preferences. I think it is correct.