# Flutter Socket-Io is not connecting to server?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to create simple chat chat app with Nodejs and Flutter. I'm using Socketio for real time communication.

When I try react client to connect my server, it is working but Flutter is not working. I used this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socket_io .

Comment: Please show us some code to understand the issue.

Comment: @Akif I'm editing my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue before. It is version issue. According to developer of that package, it is working with socket io version 2 so you should use older version of socket io on server-side.

You can see [Why my Flutter app does not connect to my local nodejs server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429692/why-my-flutter-app-does-not-connect-to-my-local-nodejs-server/65449413#65449413)

Comment: Can you suggest any plugin which works with new Socket IO.

Comment: I've tried many packages but nothing work with it. But now I don't know. You can read their description.